# Error using lambda in batch_action (Active Admin, Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem when I want to use a lambda inside a batch_action in Active Admin. This error only appears when I use a lambda since when I use a block the error disappears but the list is not updated. This is my code

```
batch_action :set_cohorts, form: -> {{cohort: Cohort.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id)}} do |ids, inputs|
  cohort = Cohort.find(inputs[:cohort])        
end

form do |f|
  inputs 'Sección' do
    f.semantic_errors
    input :cohort, as: :select, collection: -> {Cohort.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id)}
    input :name
    input :position
    input :active, as: :radio
  end
  f.actions
end
```

And the error is

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

- I am using

  - Rails 5.1.4
  - Ruby 2.4.3
  - Active Admin 2.0.0.alpha

Any suggestion is welcome. Tnks!!

Comment: Are you sure it is the `batch_action` rather than the `input :cohort ... collection: -> { ... }`? I don't know ActiveAdmin that well but the docs (ha ha) suggest that your `batch_action` is fine.

Comment: If you want to ignore lambda arguments then you probably want `->(*) { ... }` but you should make sure that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this error in Rails4.4.2

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

with the following obvious workaround

```
form_lambda = lambda do |id = nil|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, this being an older library not much updated, I expect lambda is not supported, though `proc{...}` should be fine. As to why the list is not updated I'm not clear on your intent here, typically batch_action blocks end with a `redirect_to`, eg.

```
redirect_to({action: :index}, {notice: 'Cohorts selected.'})
```